# Opening append link at other page

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile, parse-platform, append

I have the following code at Javascipt:

```
function getMuseums()
    {
     alert("get Museums");
        Museum = Parse.Object.extend("Museum");
        var query = new Parse.Query(Museum);

        query.find({
                success: function(results){
            //      alert(JSON.stringify(results));
                    var s="";
                    for(var i=0;i<results.length;i++)
                    {
                        var newMuseum= results[i];
                        var name = results[i].get("Name");
                        var address = results[i].get("Address");
                        var description = results[i].get("Description");
                        var id = results[i].id;
                        $("#list-posts").append("<li><a href='"+id+"' onclick='displayMUinfo(this.id)'>" +newMuseum.get("Name") + "" + "</a></li>");


                    }  //end of for

                        $("#list-posts").listview("refresh");
                //    $("#Museums").html(s);
                },  //end of success
                error:function(){
                    alert("error");

                }  //end of error

        });  //end of find


    }
    function displayMUinfo(clicked_id)
         {
              alert(clicked_id);
         }
```

And the following at HTML:

```
      <ul id="list-posts" data-role="listview" data-inset="true"></ul>
```

The purpose of these codes is to loop through the Museum class on Parse.com.

[CLICK ON ME PLEASE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6nVLu.jpg)

(refer to the above image link) Upon clicking on the Museum "Try Try Try", it will show up the museum's details on the other page. The problem is that, I cant get the museum's details page to open up.

Please tell me what is wrong with my code, and how to make it work. Thank You :)